# How to click login button?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I can't get the code to click the "Login to Facebook" button, I tried without success:

[Link](https://business.facebook.com/creatorstudio/home)

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/ div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]" ))).click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never use long absolute XPaths or CSS Selectors. Locators should be short and unique.
The following code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)

url = 'https://business.facebook.com/creatorstudio/home'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'Facebook login')]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "email"))).send_keys("my@email.com")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "pass"))).send_keys("my_psw")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[name='login']"))).click()
```

**UPD**
Instead of `"//div[contains(text(),'Entrar no Facebook')]"` try `"//font[contains(text(),'entrar no Facebook')]"` - the first word not capitalized and `font` tag instead of `div`. This is what I see when I translate it to Portugues

[image]

Comment: error: https://prnt.sc/uMo4nCs55LJ-

Comment: I'm not sure you used the correct Xpath in the first line...

Comment: I used both XPATH the one in the image below is what you suggested

https://prnt.sc/RrFLEwGUF_KD

it does not appear on the page
https://prnt.sc/qOuqtWd9Doco

Comment: I understand. that's because your computer is using another language. However I can't check if XPath you used is correct since my computer uses English

Answer (score 1):

Try to use relative XPATH instead of Full XPATH, It will be more accurate.

Or if possible try to share screenshot of element you are trying to access.

I found This XPATH. Hopefully it will work.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//form[@class='_9vtf']/div[2]/button").click()
```